How to use a common data type for a schema in openapi?
I've the following schema defined in my userapi.yaml file:
    SignupRequest:
      type: object
      description: Request model for user registration      
      properties:
        body:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserCreateOrUpdateRequest'

    UserUpdateRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        body:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserCreateOrUpdateRequest'

The output I'm getting is:
public class UserUpdateRequest {
   private SignupRequestBody body
   //getters and setters generated using lombok
}

public class SignupRequest {
   private SignupRequestBody body
   //getters and setters generated using lombok
}

But in the auto generated class, I want UserUpdateRequest.getbody() and SignupRequest.getBody() to be of same data type i.e. UserCreateOrUpdateRequest type :
public class UserUpdateRequest {
   private UserCreateOrUpdateRequest body
   //getters and setters generated using lombok
}

public class SignupRequest {
   private UserCreateOrUpdateRequest body
   //getters and setters generated using lombok
}

What am I doing wrong?

try removing the allOf keyword and go like: body:       $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserCreateOrUpdateRequest'

If I do that, I get this: Sibling values are not allowed alongside a $ref.
